# How to copy files and folders which start with dot in their name in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to copy files from one folder to another. My source folder has following structure

```
+ source
  + file1.txt
  + .bin
    + file2.txt
  + .ignore
```

Now I have my gulp task as follows

```
gulp.task("copy", function() {
       gulp.src("./source/**/*", { base: "source" })
           .pipe(gulp.dest("./dest/"));
});
```

This task skips copying of `.bin` folder and `.ignore` file.

How do I update my task to copy the `.bin` folder and `.ignore` file as well ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try with "dot: true"?

```
gulp.src("./source/**/*", { dot: true, base: "source" })
       .pipe(gulp.dest("./dest/"))
```

If you want to know more https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch#options

Comment: Thx. How use it for gulp.watch?